# Whitespace HTML entity?

Tags: html, html-entities

Is there a corresponding HTML entity that represents a whitespace and like this `|_|`?

Comment: http://amp-what.com/#q=space  => &#x2423, open box - space indicator

Comment: I you need this entity to display consecutive spaces, the css style `white-space: pre` might be better suited.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you mean `␣`, it's `&#x2423;` ( = `&#9251;` )

---

**Update**: above is "open box" character. more accurate symbol might be "shelf" symbol `˽` `&#x02fd;`

---

**Update 2**: there is yet another character, counterbore `⌴` `&#x2334;`, but it's rather a technical graphical symbol.

Please note, the you can have some problems with the second symbol "shelf", because it is a modifier symbol.

I'd choose the "open box" `␣`.

Comment: Not really a whitespace, but looks like |_| :)

Comment: yep, something not looking like nothing but something can't be a whitespace :)

Comment: Here are a host of them: [http://amp-what.com/#q=space](http://amp-what.com/#q=space)

Answer (score 48):

Also note `&#32;` as the entity for space rather than `&nbsp;` for non-breaking space.

Comment: Is there any particular difference between using one or the other?

Comment: The first one adds a space between strings and the second one adds a space between strings and ensures that the strings are kept in one line together with the space.

Comment: @samurai_jane Depending on the font, they might also be different sizes.

Answer (score 46):

I think you're looking for a [non-breaking space.](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp)

```
&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
&nbsp;
```

Non-breaking space.